# Is this a valid proof of the Mean Value Theorem? I feel it is too hand-wavy.

Tags: calculus

Is the following a **valid** proof of the Mean Value Theorem:

Let the continuous function $f:\Bbb{R\to R}$ be defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f'$ is continuous in $(a,b)$. Then $f'$ can't always be lower or higher than $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$, as this would imply $$f(b)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{b}{f' dx}>f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\int_a^b {dx}=f(b)$$ Alternately, $$f(b)=f(a)+\int_{a}^{b}{f' dx}<f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\int_a^b {dx}=f(b)$$ Both of these are contradictions. Hence, either $f'=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, or it increases then decreases (or decreases then decreases.

Remember that $f'$ is assumed to be continuous on $(a,b)$.

If $f'=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ throughout $(a,b)$, then we're done. If not, then as $f'$ is continuous, and takes up values both higher and lower than $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, it has to take up a value equal to $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ somewhere on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Brian- Thanks for the edit.

Comment: The mean value theorem does not require continuity of $f'$. If you remove the continuity assumption, then $f'$ needs not be Riemann or even Lebesgue integrable. (You could do with the [HK integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) but it seems bizarre, to say the least, to develop its theory in order to argue about the mean value theorem.)

Comment: That said, if you are fine with a version of the mean value theorem where $f'$ is continuous, and have shown basic properties of the Riemann integral of continuous functions without using the mean value theorem, then your proof works. In particular, this requires proving the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus without an appeal to the mean value theorem. Do you know of such a proof?

Comment: It looks like you're using the equation $$\int_a^b f'(x)\ dx = f(b) - f(a)$$ in your proof, which is circular since the MVT is used to prove this result. This also assumes $f'$ is integrable.

Comment: Mean Value Theorem is a pretty standard theorem of differential calculus and it would be better to avoid integrals. Also even if we accept this proof by integrals, I find the usual proof via Rolle's to be much simpler and more powerful because it does not assume continuity of $f'$. And you should try to understand the circularity issue here as mentioned in previous comments.